# How many times to call .SaveChangesAsync() in .BeginTransaction() EF Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

Call `SaveChangesAsync` every changes like `.Remove`, `.Update` or `.Add`

```
using (var transaction = _unitOfWork.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    var structureProfile = await _unitOfWork.StructureProfiles.GetByStructureIdAsync(id);

                    if (structureProfile != null)
                    {
                        _unitOfWork.StructureProfiles.Remove(structureProfile);
                        await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }

                    _unitOfWork.Structures.Remove(structure);
                    await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

                    await transaction.CommitAsync();
                    return NoContent();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    await transaction.RollbackAsync();
                    throw;
                }
            }
```

Or Call `SaveChangesAsync()` at last part?

```
using (var transaction = _unitOfWork.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                var structureProfile = await _unitOfWork.StructureProfiles.GetByStructureIdAsync(id);

                if (structureProfile != null)
                {
                    _unitOfWork.StructureProfiles.Remove(structureProfile);
                    //await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync(); -- Remove this part?
                }

                _unitOfWork.Structures.Remove(structure);
                await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

                await transaction.CommitAsync();
                return NoContent();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                await transaction.RollbackAsync();
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: We have no idea what your code is trying to do, nor any idea what type your `_unitOfWork` is. Please try to include relevant details in your question rather than just posting a wall of code.

Comment: DbContext **is** a Unit of Work. You don't need explicit transactions or calling `SaveChangesAsync` multiple times. `SaveChangesAsync` will persist *all* changes recorded by the Unit of Work ie the DbContext using an explicit transaction internally

Comment: Looks like you tried to implement the Repository **anti**pattern. This is a *lower level* abstraction that was used before ORMs like NHibernate and EF became commonplace. Check Gunar Peipman's [No need for Repositories and Unit of Work with EF Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) for a detailed explanation, that also explains why your `Remove` may perform 10 INSERTs and 30 UPDATEs on the side

Comment: As for your controller actions, the correct way to write them would be to inject a request-scoped or transient DbContext (**never** a singleton or long-lived one), modify the entities as needed *without* explicit transactions* and only call `SaveChangesAsync` once before returning. EF will take care of batching all changes and execute them inside a transaction

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the point of multiple SaveChanges inside an entity-framework-core transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55562646/whats-the-point-of-multiple-savechanges-inside-an-entity-framework-core-transac)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, with a single method performing the entire unit of work, you don't need the transaction: `SaveChangesAsync` will perform the actual queries as a single transaction.

Transactions become useful, for example, when the work is spread across multiple methods that each take responsability for their own part of it, including their own `SaveChangesAsync`. Then, either you explicitly commit the transaction eventually, or you dispose of its object, causing it to be rolled back.